# Excel IF statments

Tags: excel

I am trying to come up with a conventional system in a way where I can do an if statement to fulfill a list of data filled names without using a VBA macro. This would use an IF statement to see if Column D has a value to a name, and if it does, puts it in the fulfilled list, and if it does not, does nothing and places the next name there if it has a value. There will always be 8 items in unfulfilled list as it is fixed/permanent names(values in E will change), and 4 or less in the fulfilled list.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    Fulfilled List                           UnFulfilled List
      A        B                                 D         E
    Apples    50                              Apples       50 
    Oranges   75                              Peanuts      
    Grapes    60                              Oranges      75
    Avacados  100                             Grapes       60
                                              Carrots     
                                              Avacados     100
```

Here is sort of my thought. It would check the value, if value is there, place value and then place name, if value is not there, check the next cell down. However this would fail as it would take e2 no matter what, when we only want it to take valid items.

```
Cell B1 = =if(e1="",e2,e1)
Cell A1 = =if(b1="Apples,d1,d2) nested if statement possibly?
```

Any help would be appreciated how I could go about this. Thanks!

Comment: *I am trying to come up with a conventional system in a way where I can do an if statement to fulfill a list(4 max is possible) of data filled names*  < re-write this statement, in English. (i.e., what do any of these terms *mean*, given that we can't read your mind?). On that note, you might re-write your entire question, including examples of your expected outputs, or better description of what you expect to happen.

Comment: Probably you want to use `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `=IF(E1="",IF(E2="",IF(E3="",...,E3),E2),E1)`? This just goes down the column E until some value is found. If you want to match entries from the List in column A with corresponding values from the list in columns D/E then you should use some [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) or [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) function.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I believe OP is looking for a formula that they can drag down in column A and B, and it will only fill in from D & E where column E has a value.

Comment: @Bruce - Good point there. This actually makes some sense to me. But I'm not sure if this would work without VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could either use a pivot table or use an array formula such as this in A1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$3,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$3>0,ROW($E$1:$E$3)),ROW())),"")
```

**Note**: Hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter and then drag down as needed

**Note2**: In this case were using row 1, if the data was below that then (e.g. a tbale with a header) where ROW() is becomes --> ROW()-ROW(*reference to header cell*)

You need to change:

$D$1:$D$3 - this should be the full list of items in column D

$E$1:$E$3 - similarly this should be the full list of the counts in column E ( change in both places - next to the IF and next to the ROWS)

Then in column B you can have a vlookup formula such as:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>0,VLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$E$3,2,FALSE),"")
```

**Note**: this assumes you have no duplicates in column D

Again you will need to change $D$1:$E$3 so that it has all the content in those columns

Hope that helps

Comment: The formula you provided works perfect if the list of data starts in row 1. But if you have headers and the list is in, let's say `$D$2:$D$8` (and E 2-8) then it gives wrong output (at least for my testing). You might edit your formula to work independently from the first row.

Comment: @Maxhob17 this is a very good example! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to look further into the VLOOKUP functionality and Small functionality. Thank you for the help tip/answer!

Comment: Nice thinking on the `Vlookup()` part, instead of having two array formulas, which should cut down on calculation time and workbook size.

Comment: @FabianF - Updated answer for cases where the data doesn't start in row 1 if you're interested